# How do I let the user add or remove new items to the list?

Tags: python

I am looking at other python codes on this website that have a similar question, but those codes are very different than mine and seem more confusing, so it didn't help much to read them. Anyways, I wanted to see how I can let the user add or remove from the list that they created, how can I do this? Everything in this code works fine but I just want to know what I need to add on to it so I can have the user add or remove items.

```
temperatureList = list()

weather=int(input("Enter the amount of days that you are looking at for 
the weather:"))

print("Enter the high temperature for those next days: ")

for i in range(int(weather)):
    k=int(input(""))
    temperatureList.append(int(k))

sm=sum(temperatureList)

avg=sm/weather

print("SUM = ",sm)

print("AVERAGE = ",avg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For addition and deletion, you can have a loop which keeps asking the user to add and remove numbers, and show updated stats
e.g.

```
while True:
    action = int(input("Input -1 if you want to add to the list again. Or -2 if you want to remove from the list"))

    if action == -1:
        print("Enter what you want to be added ")
        add = int(input(""))
        temperatureList.append(add)
        print(temperatureList)
        sm = sum(temperatureList)

        avg = sm / weather

        print("SUM = ", sm)

        print("AVERAGE = ", avg)
    elif action == -2:
        if len(temperatureList) > 1:
            del temperatureList[-1]
            print(temperatureList)
            sm = sum(temperatureList)
            avg = sm / weather
            print("SUM = ", sm)
            print("AVERAGE = ", avg)
        else:
            print("Everything removed from the list")
```